# How to perform UPDATE with mysqli->prepare?

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

As I know there is a way to input data into a mysql database with mysqli, where you do not have to use mysql_real_escape_string. I mean like this:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO CountryLanguage VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");  
$stmt->bind_param('sssd', "something", "something2", "something3", "123");
```

Now my question: Can you do the same with UPDATE instead of INSERT? What would the expression look like? Would it look like the following:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE CountryLanguage SET some = ?, some2 = ?, some3 = ?, some4 = ?"); 
$stmt->bind_param('sssd', "something", "something2", "something3", "123");`
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: what does the sssd refer to? thanks

Comment: @jajouka check http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php which explains it (string, string, string, double)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It would look the same, but don't forget the `WHERE`. Your example is correct.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I didnt put the WHERE in my example.